# Adding single file to Windows azure service without full deployment

Tags: azure, deployment

I have a project and I have it deployed on Windows Azure cloud service, Sometimes it happens that I have to just update a image file or change a css styling. Is there a way that I can copy only the required files to Azure using RDP without missing the changes when the service is refreshed, I dont want to do a full deployment just to reflect a line of change.
Any help with this will be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full deployment is really the way Azure Cloud Services are engineered to work. However, you can take these content files, and perhaps move them to blob storage and reference them from there. This way they can be updated outside of the root deployment.

Comment: Is this still an accurate answer in 2016? Be nice to be able to upload/edit a single file without re-deploying the site.